# UnknownError: Gateway Timeout while connecting to Codecommit using asdk-sdk nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-codecommit

I have been trying to set up **CodeCommit** with aws sdk, but when i try and list al the repositories, it says `“Unknown Error Gateway Timeout”`. The secret keys **works fine with S3** but codeCommit gives **Gateway timeout error**.
Any idea
?
The user with secret keys have administrator privileges

I tried this, where codeCommit has been defined in other file. Any reason why I am getting this error?

```
const { codeCommit } = require ("./../../aws")
var hello = await codeCommit.listRepositories(params).promise();;
```

Comment: Where is this code being executed? local workstation, lambda, ec2?

Comment: Local Machine, it worked well with S3, and returns me the  list of buckets. I am using secret keys, and those secret keys'  has admin privileges

Comment: btw. you posted the question twice. maybe can remove one copy?

Comment: Deleted, so any idea, what i should do for this?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can connect to connection endpoint [[1]](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/regions.html#regions-git) via a command like curl:

```
$ curl https://git-codecommit.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
```

If not, something in your network is blocking access, presumably a firewall.